# How to save the ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> from return function?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm not so familiar with manipulating `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`. In this problem I want to save the return `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` from a function. However, I don't know weather if I code it wrong. Can anyone help me?

I've check my sql code, it work pretty fine and return the things that I want.

```java
List<HashMap<String, String>> ErrorList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ErrorList = select("SELECT * FROM process_result WHERE (status = 'Error') AND (mailBefore = 'No');");
```

```java
public List<HashMap<String, String>> select(String query) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> map = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = this.conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(query));

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
                    map.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), rs.getString(i));
                }
                output.add(map);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.print("This is select output:" + output);
        return output;
    }
```

The code don't correctly save the return value from select function.

Comment: It appears to me like you only have one instance of `HashMap<String, String>` instantiated in your method. Can't you simply change the return type to `HashMap<String, String>` rather than putting the single map into a list? Also, if your `try {` block throws an `SQLException` before map is added to the list, you will be returning an empty list, regardless of what elements exist in your map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the keys of the `map` with same column name and data for each row in the same `map` instance all the time, so you would end up with the data of the last row from the `ResultSet` in the `map` and the `output` list will have only one entry

Instead create a new `HashMap` instance for every row in the `ResultSet` and add the `map` to the list for each row:

```
while (rs.next()) {
   map = new HashMap<>(); //create one new map for every row
   for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
        map.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), rs.getString(i));
   }
   output.add(map);
}
```

Also I suggest changing the signature of the method to:

```
public List<Map<String, String>> select(String query)
```

So you do not couple your code to an implementation.

You would need to change these lines as well:

```
List<Map<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
// do not have a dependency on a particular implementation of the Map API
Map<String, String> map = null;
```