# How to pass object from routerLink in angular 7

Tags: angular

on click of hyperlink am opening employee details in new tab

```
<a [routerLink]="['/employee','details',{name:employee.empName}]" target="_blank" ></a>
```

in service am accessing that like below

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
     this.name = route.params.name;
}
```

by using above code am able to get employee name but i want to pass complete employee object.
And data is appending to url `https://localhost:4200/employee/details;name=xxxx`, i dont want to append that in Url .

If i pass employee object by converting to string , am getting data in url but am getting "page can’t be found" because i have some links in that object

Comment: Pass the unique identifier of the person, and get the details of this person thanks to this unique identifier. Just like, when you click on your question in the home page of StackOverflow, you get to a page with the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567816`. See https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-a-hero-detail-route and https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#routable-herodetailcomponent

Comment: from Angular 8 you can pass an object in state, see, e.g. https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb

Answer (score 4):

I think the thing you want is not possible with `routerLink`. The solution is to get the `uuid` of employee and append it to the link your link will be like: `https://localhost:4200/employee/details/123456789`
after that retrive user by `uuid`. This is the best solution for now!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing two different ways. [Router resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) and [router params](https://angular.io/api/router/Params).

If you are using a router resolver, you need proper configuration of route with resolve param, and your resolve method has to return a value. The data will be delivered to component by `ActivatedRoute.data`.

```js
 /* route config */
 { path: 'routePath', component: someComponent, resolve: { person: PersonService } },

 /* resolve method in the PersonService */
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
     return this.personData;
 }

 /* get the person in component */
 this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
       this.person = data.person;
 });
```

Route params are designed for simple values, not objects. If you prefer to use params, just pass the unique id in param (like the comments says), and then, get the details from server using the id.

```js
/** route config **/
{ path: 'routePath/:personId', component: SomeComponent }

/** link in html template **/
<a [routerLink]="['/employee', 'details', personId]"></a>
```